# Simplify conditional ternary expression in c#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a condition as shown below:

```
x.Customer == null ? false : x.Customer.CustomerData.IsSet
```

My IDE is saying to `Simplify conditional ternary expression`. Is there any other way to simplify this in dotnet? I recently started working with c# world it so kinda confuse on this.

Also can we also add a null check `CustomerData` too just like I have for `Customer` in a single line as well?

I tried like this -

```
Field("isSet", x => x.Customer?.CustomerData?.IsSet ?? false);
```

When I try this, it gives an error as -

> An expression tree lambda may not contain conditional access
> expression

Comment: Something like `x.Customer?.CustomerData?.IsSet ?? false` probably.

Comment: `Field("isSet", x => x.Customer?.CustomerData?.IsSet ?? false);` When I try this, it complains - `An expression tree lambda may not contain conditional access expression` @JackT.Spades

Comment: Well it seems like your IDE is being a bit silly there, not understanding that this is part of an expression tree. You should silence that warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your expression is boolean so there's no need to write ternary operator. You can write it this way:

```
x.Customer != null && x.Customer.CustomerData.IsSet
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
bool result =  x.Customer?.CustomerData?.IsSet ?? false
```

So if any of Customer or CutomerData is null, default will be false, otherwise IsSet will be returned.